# Import/export clipping path only from Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I'm working with another designer and we exchange PSD's where we both create clipping masks for objects in the photograph.

As the files are quite big, I was wondering if there is a way to only exchange the clipping masks? That way we don't have to shuffle the big files back and forth.

I have looked online for an answer - but couldn't find one.

Comment: Leave one blank layer and the paths in the file and save a copy.

Answer (score 1):

Um if I understand correctly

1. On the Layers / Channels / Paths area go into Paths
2. Use the Path Menu and choose Save Path
3. Delete everything else

If you use this option (same as Scott's comment) make sure you use either .TIF, .EPS, .PSD or .JPG (not web jpg though) otherwise it won't save your paths.

Or

1. Fill the clipping path with a solid color like a lime green or something
2. Delete everything else

Comment: Although the title might make you think otherwise, I believe the OP is talking about clipping MASKS, not clipping PATHS.

Comment: @TunaMaxx same approach applies, just the mask as a channel

Comment: @joojaa - No, sorry. Nothing in this answer applies to masks. While you and I can easily see the similarities in how one would do something like this using masks, this answer answer is specifically about using clipping paths.

Comment: Depends, some peole can take hints even if they dont know exact procedures. But right some people can never het the hint.